# Elasticsearch : Multi match query on nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am having a problem with multi-match query in RoR. I have Elastic Search configured and working however I am working on setting up aggregations which so far seem to work, but for whatever reason I am not able to search on the field which I am aggregating. This is the extract from my model:

```
    settings :index => { :number_of_shards => 1 } do
        mapping do
          indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
          indexes :name
          indexes :summary
          indexes :description

          indexes :occasions, type: 'nested' do
            indexes :id, type: 'integer'
            indexes :occasion_name, type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed

           ... 

          end
        end
      end




  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    self.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :summary, :description],
                 include: {
                     occasions:           { only: [:id, :occasion_name] },
                     courses:             { only: [:id, :course_name] },
                     allergens:           { only: [:id, :allergen_name] },
                     cookingtechniques:   { only: [:id, :name] },
                     cuisine:             { only: [:id, :cuisine_name]}
                 })
  end


class << self
    def custom_search(query)
      __elasticsearch__.search(query: multi_match_query(query), aggs: aggregations)
    end


    def multi_match_query(query)
      {
          multi_match:
          {
              query: query,
              type: "best_fields",
              fields: ["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6", "occasion_name^6", "course_name^6", "cookingtechniques.name^5"],
              operator: "and"
          }
      }
    end
```

I am able to search on all fields as specified in the multi_match_query apart of "occasion_name" which happens to be the field I am aggregating. I have checked that the field is correctly indexed (using elastic search-head plugin). I am also able to display the facets with the aggregated occasion_names in my view. I tried everything I can think of, including removing the aggregation and searching on occasion_name, but still no luck. 
(I am using the elasticsearch-rails gem)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit:

I got this ES query from rails:

```
@search=
  #<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007f91244df460
   @definition=
    {:index=>"recipes",
     :type=>"recipe",
     :body=>
      {:query=>
        {:multi_match=>
          {:query=>"Christmas",
           :type=>"best_fields",
           :fields=>["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6", "occasion_name^6", "course_name^6", "cookingtechniques.name^5"],
           :operator=>"and"}},
       :aggs=>
        {:occasion_aggregation=>
          {:nested=>{:path=>"occasions"}, :aggs=>{:id_and_name=>{:terms=>{:script=>"doc['occasions.id'].value + '|' + doc['occasions.occasion_name'].join(' ')", :size=>35}}}}}}},
```

This is an example of all that gets indexed for 1 of my dummy recipes I use for testing (the contents are meaningless - I use this only for testing):

```
{
"_index": "recipes",
"_type": "recipe",
"_id": "7",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"id": 7,
"name": "Mustard-stuffed chicken",
"summary": "This is so good we'd be surprised if this chicken fillet recipe doesn't become a firm favourite. Save it to your My Good Food collection and enjoy",
"description": "Heat oven to 200C/fan 180C/gas 6. Mix the cheeses and mustard together. Cut a slit into the side of each chicken breast, then stuff with the mustard mixture. Wrap each stuffed chicken breast with 2 bacon rashers – not too tightly, but enough to hold the chicken together. Season, place on a baking sheet and roast for 20-25 mins.",
"occasions": [
{
"id": 9,
"occasion_name": "Christmas"
}
,
{
"id": 7,
"occasion_name": "Halloween"
}
,
{
"id": 8,
"occasion_name": "Bonfire Night"
}
,
{
"id": 10,
"occasion_name": "New Year"
}
],
"courses": [
{
"id": 9,
"course_name": "Side Dish"
}
,
{
"id": 7,
"course_name": "Poultry"
}
,
{
"id": 8,
"course_name": "Salad"
}
,
{
"id": 10,
"course_name": "Soup"
}
],
"allergens": [
{
"id": 6,
"allergen_name": "Soya"
}
,
{
"id": 7,
"allergen_name": "Nut"
}
,
{
"id": 8,
"allergen_name": "Other"
}
,
{
"id": 1,
"allergen_name": "Dairy"
}
],
"cookingtechniques": [
{
"id": 15,
"name": "Browning"
}
],
"cuisine": {
"id": 1,
"cuisine_name": "African"
}
}
}
```

EDIT 2:

I managed to make the search work for occasions as suggested by @rahulroc, but now I can't search on anything else...

```
    def multi_match_query(query)
  {
      nested:{
           path: 'occasions',
          query:{
      multi_match:
      {
          query: query,
          type: "best_fields",
          fields: ["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6", "occasion_name^6", "course_name^6", "cookingtechniques.name^5"],
          operator: "and"
      }
    }

      }
  }
end
```

**UPDATE: Adding multiple nested fields** - I am trying to add the rest of my aggregations but I am facing similar problem as before. My end goal will be to use the aggregations as filters so I need to add about 4 more nested fields to my query (I also would like to have the fields searchable) Here is the working query as provided by @rahulroc + the addition of another nested field which I can't search on. As before in terms of indexing everything is working and I can display the aggregations for the newly added field, but I can't search on it. I tried different variations of this query but I couldn't make it work (the rest of the fields are still working and searchable - the problem is just the new field):

```
 def multi_match_query(query)
      {

        bool: {
            should: [
                {
                    nested:{
                        path: 'occasions',
                        query: {
                            multi_match:
                            {
                                      query: query,
                                      type: "best_fields",
                                      fields: ["occasion_name"]

                                  }
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    nested:{
                        path: 'courses',
                        query: {
                            multi_match:
                                {
                                    query: query,
                                    type: "best_fields",
                                    fields: ["course_name"]

                                }
                        }
                    }
                },

                {
                    multi_match: {
                        query: query,
                        fields:["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6"],

                    }
                }
            ]
        }


      }
    end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with rails but have some ES experience. Are you able to show the JSON query that gets sent to ElasticSearch?

Comment: Hi, I just edit my first post - I have included the query. Thanks

Comment: occasion_name is a nested field. It can not be directly accessed in match query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a separate nested clause for matching a nested field

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "occassions",
                    "query": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "Christmas",
                            "fields": ["occassion_name^2"]
                        }
                    }
                } 
            },
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Christmas",
                    "fields":["name^9", "summary^8", "cuisine_name^7", "description^6","course_name^6"]                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to make the search work for occasions as per edit 2, but now I can't search anything else

Comment: The other fields do not belong to the nested scope of occassions. Other fields need to be in their respective scope. Make separate clauses in bool-should clause. I will provide the full query in some time.

Comment: I am risking to get annoying, but I need help again... I tried to add my other aggregations following the method described by @rahulroc - adding another { nested:{path: 'courses',query: {multi_match: {query: query,type: "best_fields",  fields: ["course_name"]}}}} inside the "should" clause, but the newly added nested field is not searchable. I checked the ElasticSearch Definitive Guide, but there is example only with one nested field. In another question on StackOverflow, someone has provided a query exactly the way I am doing it with multiple nested fields but mine doesn't work...

Comment: Please update your question with ur most recent query.

Comment: I have just updated it with the new query. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't the nested field need to be `occassions.occassion_name^2`? (i.e. with `occassions.` prefix)

Comment: I have a doubt on the above answer, can someone please explain. if the two queries are kept inside should, then it is not the best match from all the fields right? it is always score = First should clause score + best match of fields from the second clause